# What is the common PCL profile version for Itinero + Mapsui + OsmSharp?

Tags: c#, xamarin, openstreetmap

I'm trying to install Itinero + Mapsui + OsmSharp NuGet packages into Xamarin's PCL project.

After unsuccessful try of using Profil49 I've switched to Profile111 to be able to install Mapsui.
But now I can install neither Itinero nor OsmSharp with error:

```
Could not install package 'Itinero 0.39.2-rc1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

What is PCL profile version should be used?

Not sure if it has any influence but I'm using Visual Studio for Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use **Profile44**

See https://github.com/itinero/routing/issues/83 for details